# search json data which come in search : angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am getting a json data from a ajax.
i want to show only those data only which came in search.

```
<input  class="form-control" ng-model="search.name" id="exampleInputEmail1">
     <table id="searchObjResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]
```

May be its a easy fix but i am very new in angular.Any pointer will be really helpfull

Comment: are you facing any issue with this code or you want some sample for ajax based search

Comment: i want only filter result in table but here all json in my table and filter result coming after i type

Comment: so remove input and just define your search pattern in controller `$scope.search = { name: 'Mary' };`

Comment: i am not getting what ur trying to say @kTT

Comment: @supersaiyan Can you describe your problem? The code you provided above is working. Please write what you want to achive.

Comment: ok.. so what out is coming is : table on the page and if i am searching the result its filtering thats part is working fine...
My NEED is : i want that table hide by default and want to get the data which is type by user

Comment: @supersaiyan Add `ng-show="search.name"` to <table> or <tr> element (it depends if you want to hide headers). It will hide all rows until user enter some text to search field. Is that what you want?

Comment: that exactly i want bt its not happening 
 <table id="searchObjResults"  ng-show="search.name"  >
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict" >
    <td class="name">{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td class="phone">{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>.. i did this.. table is hide but when i am typing its not coming in search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to hide all results and show only that match the search pattern.

You can use ng-show to limit the visibility of the table. [jsfiddle of below code](https://jsfiddle.net/tj6v5Lqm/2/)

```
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                     {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                     {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                     {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                     {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                     {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>
<input class="form-control" ng-model="search.name" id="exampleInputEmail1">
<table id="searchObjResults" ng-show="search.name">
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search">
      <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
```